# underscore unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="styles_section">
        <select>
            <%_.each(colorOption, function(color){ %>
            <option><%= color.get("color_name") %></option>
            <% }); %>
        </select>
    </script>
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code.

**EDIT:**

Here's the json code as requested.

```
var myColors = [{ color_name: 'white', color_code: '#ffffff'},
                {color_name: 'black', color_code: '#000000'}];
```

Here's the backbone part.

```
var colorOption = new Backbone.Collection(myColors);

    var colors = new SelectColorView({
        model: colorOption,
    });
```

Comment: you want to consruct drop down using javascript and js array right

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh, Yes, together with backbone.js, I did not include the full code since that's the only part I'm having error.

Comment: the way you did is wrong ,please post your json array too here

Comment: Please change script tag type to `text/x-handlebars`, not a `text/javascript`

Comment: @FizerKhan, but I'm not using handlebars

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh, For underscore,the type will be `text/template`.

Comment: In your case, browser is trying to execute the `script` tag code since its type is `text/javascript`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script tag is also used for micro templates. For micro template, script tag `type` should not be `text/javascript`.

For micro templates, script tag is as follows

```
 <script type="text/template"></script>
```

By setting the type to "text/template", it's not a script that the browser can understand, and so the browser will simply ignore it. This allows you to put anything in there, which can then be extracted later and used by a templating library to generate HTML snippets.

Comment: <script type = "text/template"></script> solves the problem thanks.